Export sheet in a workbook to CSV file in the same location every week
I have a sheet in a workbook I would like to export to a csv file that gets updated every week.
So ideally, I want the VBA code to export whatever data is in the sheet and overwrite what was existing in the path.
The range of data is from A to AJ.
The path of the folder will be on "C:\Users\HS"
I tried to adapt @VBasic2008 code at the location below to no avail.
EXCEL-VBA How to export to a CSV... a custom range of columns?
The result displays/flashes on the screen when I run it but doesn't get saved at the location specified.
Here is exactly what I had:
Option Explicit

Sub ExportColumnsToCSV()
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 1
    Const sColsList As String = "A:AJ"
    
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = sws.Parent
    
    Dim srrg As Range
    Dim slCell As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Rows(sfRow)
        Set slCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet.", vbCritical, "Export to CSV"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sCols)
        If srg Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = Intersect(srrg, sws.Columns(sCols(n)))
        Else
            Set srg = Union(srg, Intersect(srrg, sws.Columns(sCols(n))))
        End If
    Next n
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    srg.Copy
    dwb.Worksheets(1).Range(dFirst).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = swb.Path & "C:\Users\HS"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir dFolderPath
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim dFilePath As String
    dFilePath = dFolderPath _
        & Left(swb.Name, InStrRev(swb.Name, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
    ' Optionally, out-comment previous line and uncomment next one
    ' to save with the current worksheet name.
    'dFilePath = dFolderPath & sws.Name & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Local:=False
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Thank you
HS

Have you tried to debug the code using a breakpoint on the line with dwb.SaveAs ... and make sure the path is correct?


I just tried that, and it creates a new workbook with all the cell data. 2.When breakpoint is removed, it just flashes the workbook, and then vanishes. Thank you


When you hit the breakpoint, you should also hover your mouse over dFilePath to check the value.

Here is an update with all previously mentioned comments and your recent request
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If TodayIsTheDay Then
        ExportColumnsToCSV
    End If

End Sub

Private Property Get TodayIsTheDay() As Boolean

    ' = 5 would be Friday
    ' = 6 would be Saturday
    ' = 1 would be Monday so on and so forth
    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 5 Then TodayIsTheDay = True

End Property

Private Sub ExportColumnsToCSV()

    Dim wsTheWorksheetYouWant As Worksheet

    ' This is where you are going to change the worksheet name to the name you need
    
    Set wsTheWorksheetYouWant = Application.Worksheets("yourWorksheetName")

    Dim lBottomRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
        lBottomRow = wsTheWorksheetYouWant.Range("$A:$A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lBottomRow <= 1 Then
        ' This assumes there is no data but still has coulmn headers.

        MsgBox "there is only 1 row of data here"
    Else
        Dim rngTheRangeYouWant as range
        Set rngTheRangeYouWant = wsTheWorksheetYouWant.Range("$A$1:$AJ$" & lBottomRow)

        With rngTheRangeYouWant
        
            Dim oNewWorkbook As Workbook
            Set oNewWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
            
            rngTheRangeYouWant.Copy
            With oNewWorkbook
                .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                
                ' If you want to make the name dynamic to the date then do it like this
                Dim DatedFileName As String                     ' I Broke it up this way so you can make the filename dynamic as well
                DatedFileName = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & "SomeGenericName" & ".csv"
                
                'Change this to your path with extension like
                .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\yourpath\" & DatedFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Local:=False
                
                .Close
                    
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        
        End With

    End If

    Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Nothing
    Set oNewWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub


Thank you for the quick response. I will spend some time testing it and come back if I have questions.

Hello All, @BWing, one issue I noticed with the code is that it does not run with the sections of "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose" and "Private Property Get TodayIsTheDay".  I changed the date to Monday = 1, and it did not export a csv today, Monday. If I remove the 2 sections named above and manually run it, it exports the csv to my sharepoint location. Thank you

Hope this helps, I think with the modifications in the comments should work for your application.
Sub ExportColumnsToCSV()

Dim rngTheRangeYouWant As Range
Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AJ")

Dim lBottomRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    lBottomRow = rngTheRangeYouWant.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
If lBottomRow <= 1 Then
    ' This assumes there is no data but still has coulmn headers.

    MsgBox "there is only 1 row of data here"
Else
    Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AJ$" & lBottomRow)

    With rngTheRangeYouWant
        
            Dim oNewWorkbook As Workbook
            Set oNewWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
            
            rngTheRangeYouWant.Copy
            With oNewWorkbook
                .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                
                                        'Change this to your path with extension like
                    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\yourPath\ThisFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Local:=False
                    .Close
                    
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        
    End With
    
End If

Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Nothing
Set oNewWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub

Please mark my response as the answer if it works for you, thanks! Good Luck!

Thank you for the response. I only get the MsgBox "there is only 1 row of data here" when I run it. The data in the sheet spans 18 rows from A to AJ with headers.

I modified my answer after the original post I realized my logic operation I had for bottom row wasn't right, try again it should be if lBottomRow <=1 before my correction I had my less than facing the wrong way like >=


It worked great! File was created and saved at the path on the local computer. 2. I tried to save it to SharePoint but that wouldn't work. 3. In addition, please can you add a code to it to allow this VBA to export every week for example? Thank you


I'm sorry, you will need to be more specific, break it down to me so I can understand, how you see this operating. Do you foresee this being a type of button click event where it would process the information after you click the button or would it be some timer that would periodically check and use date naming conventions to know if you have already saved the file for today, how do you see this working?

You could do a worksheet on open check today's date if today equals Friday ask user if they would like to save the data. While doing an if comparison to check for the file in your folder structure

Sorry for the late response. It is not going to be button clicked. Ideally, I would like it to be a timer that will use date naming conversion or maybe updates and overwrites exported sheet after every 200 hours for example. Thank you

Sorry for the delay in response, so I am going to assume you know what I mean when I say that this code belongs in the Workbook code but ya this will go in the workbook code for the workbook open event
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()



    Dim TodayIsTheDay As Boolean
    TodayIsTheDay = IsTodayTheDay
    
    If TodayIsTheDay Then
        ExportColumnsToCSV
    End If

End Sub
Private Property Get IsTodayTheDay() As Boolean

    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 5 Then IsTodayTheDay = True

End Property

Private Sub ExportColumnsToCSV()

Dim rngTheRangeYouWant As Range
Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AJ")

Dim lBottomRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    lBottomRow = rngTheRangeYouWant.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
If lBottomRow <= 1 Then
    ' This assumes there is no data but still has coulmn headers.

    MsgBox "there is only 1 row of data here"
Else
    Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AJ$" & lBottomRow)

    With rngTheRangeYouWant
        
            Dim oNewWorkbook As Workbook
            Set oNewWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
            
            rngTheRangeYouWant.Copy
            With oNewWorkbook
                .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                
                ' If you want to make the name dynamic to the date then do it like this
                Dim DatedFileName As String                     ' I Broke it up this way so you can make the filename dynamic as well
                DatedFileName = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & "SomeGenericName" & ".csv"
                
                                        'Change this to your path with extension like
                    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\bwing\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\" & DatedFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Local:=False
                    .Close
                    
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        
    End With
    
End If

Set rngTheRangeYouWant = Nothing
Set oNewWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub


I had fun with this lol if you can't tell with my variable naming conventions, after reading back through the post i see i failed to implement the file path you were naming but i think i made it pretty straightforward

No need to apologize for the delay. And the file type is pretty straight forward. I am going to test it and give feedback soon. Thank you for the help.

I was also thinking maybe have it set to a workbook close event instead of open so it will save after edits, also you didn't really need the extra variable creation in the event module it could just say If IsTodayTheDay Then ExportColumnsToCSV, if that doesn't make sense I can post new code, and if you don't understand the code i set it to run on fridays, change ' Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 5 ' to whatever you want to change the day it saves on.

If I understood well, I don't think the workbook close event is needed since the original. source workbook will always be saved by the folks making the changes.

please when you get the chance, can you post a new code that exports columns to csv for a specific sheet in a workbook. I failed to mention the workbook has other sheets. Thank you for your help
